# Custom JsonConverter - unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

## Goal

I need to serialize some classes (i'm trying to use JSON.NET for this). Some have have self references. For 1 of them i need to be able to decide which fields to serialize (2 possible selections). This class is the hard part. This is a simplified example of the classes (Node is the special class):

```
// classes

class TreeObject
{ }

class Node : TreeObject // needs to be specially serialized
{
    public string name;
    public List<TreeObject> childs; // can contain self-reference

    public Node()
    {
        name = null;
        childs = new List<TreeObject>();
    }
}
```

I tried creating a JsonConverter for the Node class by inheriting from JsonConverter and overriding the methods: "CanConvert", "WriteJson" (for serialization), "ReadJson" (for de-serialization).

This how i tried to use my "NodeConverter":

```
// create object
Node parent = new Node();
parent.name = null;
parent.childs.Add(parent);

// create settings
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
settings.Converters = new[] {new NodeConverter()}; // add my converter
settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;

// serialize
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent, Formatting.Indented, settings);

// expected result
json == @"{
            ""$id"": ""1"",
            ""$type"": ""Node, test"", 
            ""childs"": [
              {
                ""$ref"": ""1""
              }
            ]
          }"; // the project is called "test"
```

## Problem

- i need to preserve references (ex: $id and $ref fields)
- i also need to preserve type information because i'm using polymorphism/inheritance (ex: $type fields)

but JSON.NET stops handling these features automatically when i try to add my JsonConverter to the JsonSerializerSettings (for serialization and deserialization).

## Questions

- how do i get JSON.NET to handle the preservation of object references and type information when i use my own JsonConverter?
- how do i get the deserialization to work properly as well?
- is there a JSON library that's more suitable for this?

i've spent hours looking up how to make this work, any help would be appreciated

EDIT: i've tried to shorten my question

EDIT:

## The Serialization & Deserialization Logic looks like this:

```
string SerializeNode(Node node)
{
    if(node.name == null)
    {
        compress(node);
        string strNode = (serialize all fields except the name field);
        decompress(node);

        return strNode;
    }
    else
    {
        return (serialize only the name field); 
    }
}

Node DeserializeNode(string strNode)
{
    if(strNode does not have name field)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        deserialize all strNode fields and assign them to node;
        decompress(node);

        return node; 
    }
    else
    {
        return KnownNodes[strNode name field]; 
        // where KnownNodes is a Dictionary<string, Node> 
    }
}
```

Of course i still want JSON.NET to preserve references (with the PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects option for now) and also include the type names with TypeNameHandling.Auto. The dictionary avoids unnecessary data and makes sure that the same instance is shared, for all objects with the same name.

Comment: In the beginning of your question, you say that you need to conditionally serialize some fields based on logic that is not in the class being serialized.  Since that is the real problem you are trying to solve, can you give more details about that?  What fields?  What is the logic?  And what is the expected output?  The actual solution might not involve a converter at all.  But you haven't provided enough details to go on at this point.

Comment: it's funny how your question just made me realize that, it seems all the information (at least for serialization) is actually be available in the Node class. but i'm not sure how to go about it yet.

Comment: i just made the expected result consistent with the serialization logic. i hope it's less confusing now.

Comment: maybe i should start writing my own parser

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at : http://christianarg.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/serializing-and-deserializing-inherited-types-with-json-anything-you-want/

```
[TestMethod]
 public void List_Test()
 {
    var resource = new Resource() { ResourceProperty = "Resource" };
    var video = new Video() { ResourceProperty = "Video", VideoProperty = "VideoMP4" };

   var list = new List<Resource>() { resource, video };

   // Again the important part are the settings
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
   {
      TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
   };

   var serializedList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, settings);

   var deserializedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Resource>> (serializedList, settings);

   // And we recover the information with NO data loss
   Assert.AreEqual("Resource", deserializedList[0].ResourceProperty);
   Assert.AreEqual("VideoMP4", ((Video)deserializedList[1]).VideoProperty);
}
```

## Edit:

Personally I use string extentsion:

```
    public static bool DeserializeJson<T>(this String str, out T item)
    {
        var returnResult = default(T);
        var success = Ui.Instance.Try(
            () =>
            {
                returnResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(str);
            },
            "Deserializing json " + typeof(T),
            "Deserializing json done",
            "Deserializing json failed",
            isCritical:false
        );
        item = returnResult;
        return success;
    }
```

And then I could use

```
Node node;
if(GetJson(service, out jsonstring) && jsonstring.DeserializeJson(out node)){
```

or

```
TreeObject node;
```

or

```
... jsonstring.DeserializeJson<TreeObject>(out node)){
```

Comment: Thanks but, your example doesn't show how I can exclude fields from serialization. But more importantly, how I can deserialize objects and *decide* whether to create a new object or use an existing instance, of the object being deserialized. In my example, I have already enabled TypeNameHandling.Auto, and I'm also using PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects.

Comment: Ui.Instance.Try is just a fancy try-catch for trace to ensure you get expected execution path.

Comment: In your 2nd example: DeserializeJson seems to be calling itself, but I don't see you creating any new instance of Node. I also don't see you using any existing instance of Node. Why are you using JavaScriptSerializer instead of JSON.NET?

Comment: DeserializeJson is string extension method that returns bool as success and class instance by **out** parameter modifier. New instance is created by **default(T)** (in order to have correct type info if deserializing fails due to ex. incorrect data) and re-referenced in Deserialize method.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same exact issue 5 years later. Here is an example of keeping references properly resolved. Note the call to `serializer.ReferenceResolver` which does the magic.

```
    public class EntityConverter : JsonConverter<Entity>
    {
        public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, Entity value, JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            var me = new JObject();
            me["$id"] = new JValue( serializer.ReferenceResolver.GetReference( serializer, value ) );
            me["your_array"] = JArray.FromObject( value.components, serializer );
            me["your_other_values"] = new JValue( value.tag );

            me.WriteTo( writer );
        }

        public override Entity ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Entity existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            var o = JObject.Load( reader );
            var id = (string)o["$id"];
            if( id != null )
            {
                var entity = new Entity();
                serializer.Populate( o.CreateReader(), entity );
                return entity;
            }
            else
            {
                var reference = (string)o["$ref"];
                return serializer.ReferenceResolver.ResolveReference( serializer, reference ) as Entity;
            }
        }
    }
```